# Convert a string into multiple variables and values

Tags: php, string, variables

I would like to convert the string:

```
{ "summonerLevel": 6, "name": "Nautilus", "dataVersion": 0, "internalName": "nautilus", "profileIconId": 4, "summonerId": 37399097, "acctId": 200656209, "revisionDate": "Sep 4, 2013 12:43:34 p.m.", "revisionId": 0 }
```

Into something like :

```
$summonerLevel=6;
$name="Nautilus";
$dataVersion=0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just decode the JSON in your string, and then extract it:

```
$vars = json_decode('{ ... }');
extract($vars);
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! just added true to json_decode to make it work.
`$vars = json_decode('{ ... }',true);
extract($vars);`